# How can I find python library path?

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, interpreter

I am trying to find my openCV library path. I am pretty sure it is existing. When I run command panel on desktop to learn openCV version, I can see version of openCV. Here the result:
[image]

I guess my base interpreter path is : [image]

But I couldn't find openCV library in this file. I want to use my base interpreter for another project which in another file. So I need to find openCV library is there. How can I find my openCV library path?

Also when I try to install openCV from pycharm>settings>interpreter>... , after installation  cv2.**version** not working on desktop. I don't understand what is happening between this virtual environtments and base interprater.

Comment: What is the output of only `cv2` instead of `cv2.__version__` in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an example

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
```

[check out here](https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in an enviroment always activate environment to install packages within the environment.

```
$ conda activate xxx
$ conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

To find the interpreter, first activate your environment, run python and check the interpreter executable path.

```
$ conda activate xxx
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
```

If you haven't created an environment then execute below commands on cmd.

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
```